# Компилятор пропускает большую часть кода

Tags: python-3.5

Почему пропускается большая часть кода (пропускается весь цикл в main)?

Вот сам код:

```
EMPTY = " "

NUM_OF_SQUARES = 9

board = EMPTY

answer = EMPTY

X = "X"

O = "O"

TIE = "Ничья"



def instruction():
    """Инструкция"""

    print("""Вам дана доска с цифрами(клетками):
          0  |  1  | 2 
        _____|_____|____
          3  |  4  | 5
        _____|_____|____
          6  |  7  | 8
             |     |

    Цифры- это точки куда ставить свой значок.         

    """)


def ask_yes_no(question):
    """Часть для вопросов с ответами 'Да' или 'Нет' """

    response = None

    while response != "n" or response != "y":
        response = input(question).lower()
        return response


def ask_number(question, low, high):
    """Просит ввести число из диапозона"""

    response = None

    while response not in range(low, high):
        response = int(input(question))
    return response


def first_move():
    """Предоставление выбора первого хода"""

    response = ask_yes_no("Хотите ли вы ходить первым?(y/n) ")

    if response == 'y':

        human = X
        computer = O
        return human, computer

    elif response == 'n':

        computer = X
        human = O

        return human, computer


def new_board():
    board = []

    for sqare in range(NUM_OF_SQUARES):
        board.append(EMPTY)
    return board


def display_board(board):
    print("\n\t", board[0], "|", board[1], "|", board[2])
    print("\t-----------")
    print("\t", board[3], "|", board[4], "|", board[5])
    print("\t-----------")
    print("\t", board[6], "|", board[7], "|", board[8], "\n")


def allowed_moves(board):
    """Возможные ходы"""
    moves = []

    for square in range(NUM_OF_SQUARES):

        if board[square] == EMPTY:
            moves.append(square)

    return moves


def winner(board):
    """Определяет победителя"""

    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0, 1, 2),
                   (3, 4, 5),
                   (6, 7, 8),
                   (0, 3, 6),
                   (1, 4, 7),
                   (2, 5, 8),
                   (0, 4, 8),
                   (2, 4, 6)
                   )

    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:

        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]]:
            winner = board[row[0]]

            return winner

        if EMPTY not in board:
            return TIE


def human_movee(board, human):
    """Ход человека"""

    move = None

    while move not in allowed_moves():
        move = ask_number("Выбери одно из полей в диапозоне от 0 до 8: ", 0, NUM_OF_SQUARES)

        if move not in allowed_moves():
            print("Эта клетка уже занята. Нужно выбрать другое.")
    print("Понято, принято")

    return move


def computer_movee(computer, human, board):
    board = board[:]

    BEST_MOVES = (0, 2, 6, 8, 4, 1, 3, 5, 7)

    print("Выбераю поле номер ", end=" ")

    for move in allowed_moves(board):
        board[move] = computer

        if winner(board) == computer:
            print(move)
            return move
        board[move] = EMPTY
    for move in allowed_moves(board):
        board[move] = human

        if winner(board) == human:
            print(move)
            return move

        board[move] = EMPTY

    for move in BEST_MOVES:
        if move in allowed_moves(board):
            print(move)

            return move


def next_turn(turn):
    if turn == X:
        return O
    else:
        return X


def congrat_winner(the_winner, human, computer):
    if the_winner == computer:
        print("Победил я(компьютер)")

    elif the_winner == human:
        print("Вы победили!")

    elif the_winner == TIE:
        print("Ничья...");



def main():
    instruction()

    human, computer = first_move()

    turn = X

    board = new_board()

    display_board(board)

    while not winner(board):

        if turn == human:
            move = human_movee(board, human)
            board[move] = human

        elif turn == computer:
            move = computer_movee(computer, human, board)
            board[move] = computer

        turn=next_turn(turn)

        display_board(board)

    the_winner = winner(board)

    congrat_winner(the_winner, human, computer)


main()

input("Enter, что бы выйти")
```

Comment: Посмотри, что возвращает winner(board) в условии цикла и все поймешь.

Comment: Отладку в руки и вперёд! Для начала расставьте хотя бы `print`ы, чтобы увидеть — какое значение возвращает функция winner, сколько итераций выполняется внутри цикла в функции winner и так далее